# No "Mono" option for each track

Tags: audio, mp3, audacity

I followed this link https://audacity.wonderhowto.com/how-to/remove-vocals-from-songs-using-audacity-162272/ to remove vocal from a song in mp3 format.

When I reach "Step 4 Set Each Track to Mono", there is no "Mono" option in the menu of each track. See the following screenshot. I wonder what is going wrong? Thanks.

[image]

My audacity version is Audacity 2.2.0. Its build Information is:

```
Program build date: Jan 29 2016
Commit Id: No revision identifier was provided
Build type: Release build
Compiler: GCC 5.4.0
Installation Prefix: /usr
Settings folder: /home/t/.audacity-data
```

I run it in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Something has changed in v2.2.0+ as the menu option is there in v2.1.2